# Difficulties using findContours in OpenCV to detect PostNet barcode in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

I have having a difficult time getting findContours to return the shorter lines that come from a postnet barcode.  It returns the same number of contours as lines but when looking at the contours they don't match what is there.  It seems the contours don't equate to the lines.  I suspect the shorter lines are not being seen by the function.  Perhaps it has to do with how I am cleaning up the image but I don't know.  Perhaps someone can see something in this code and offer a suggestion?

[image]

```
    std::string barcode;
    char retval[32];
    char buffer[256];
    int line = 0; 
    uchar pastPixel = 0;
    bool iswhite = false;
    cv::Mat thinImg;
    cv::Mat binary_image;

    // Transform source image to gray if it is not
    if( inputImage.channels() == 3 )
    {
        cv::cvtColor( inputImage, inputImage, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    }

    // Get binary image via Otsu:
    cv::threshold( inputImage, inputImage, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU );
    cv::imwrite( "/tmp/postnet1.tif", inputImage );

    // Apply Morphology. Erosion + Dilation: Set rectangular structuring element of size 3 x 3:
    cv::Mat SE = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3) );
    cv::morphologyEx( inputImage, inputImage, cv::MORPH_ERODE, SE, cv::Point(-1,-1), 1 );
    cv::imwrite( "/tmp/postnet2.tif", inputImage );

    // Set rectangular structuring element of size 5 x 5:
    SE = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5) );
    cv::morphologyEx( inputImage, inputImage, cv::MORPH_DILATE, SE, cv::Point(-1,-1), 1);
    cv::imwrite( "/tmp/postnet3.tif", inputImage );

    // Extend borders to avoid skeleton artifacts, extend 5 pixels in all directions:
//  cv::copyMakeBorder( inputImage, inputImage, 5, 5, 5, 5, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, 1 );
    cv::imwrite( "/tmp/postnet4.tif", inputImage );

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> vertical_dim;
    cv::Mat verticalStructure = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(1,40));
    // find the contours of the vertical lines.
    cv::bitwise_not(inputImage, binary_image);
    cv::findContours(binary_image, vertical_dim, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    bool not_segment = false;
    // skip first and last one.
    for( int x = vertical_dim.size()-1; x >= 0 && not_segment == false; x-=5 )
    {
        // check to see if multiple sequences of 5 sided polygons are present excluding the initial and terminating contour.
        // Concatenate the points of the contours into a single contour
        std::vector<cv::Point> barcode_contour;
        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) 
        {
            barcode_contour.insert(barcode_contour.end(), vertical_dim[x-i].begin(), vertical_dim[x-i].end());
        }
        
        std::vector<cv::Point>hull;
        cv::convexHull(barcode_contour, hull, CV_CLOCKWISE, true);


        cv::Mat contours_result = inputImage.clone();
        cv::drawContours(contours_result, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>{ hull }, 0, cv::Scalar(0,255,255), 3 );
        cv::imwrite( "/tmp/postnet7.tif", contours_result );

        std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
        std::vector<cv::Point> barcode_segment;

        // Apply polygon approximation to the combined contour
        std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
        cv::approxPolyDP(barcode_segment, approx, 0.02 * cv::arcLength(barcode_contour, true), true);

        // Check if the approximation is a convex polygon with exactly 5 sides
        if (approx.size() != 5 || !cv::isContourConvex(approx)) 
        {
            // Extract the barcode digits from the image and return as a string
            not_segment = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you assume contours to come in a specific order? why don't you simply drawContours() what you have and look at it? draw into a color image so you can tell what's original and what is drawn.

Comment: Actually, I do draw it out but it seemed to indicate that they were in a reverse order primarily.  But your comment seems to indicate that it was a random chance.  I will go back and sort them.  Thanks.

Comment: If you need to read or write barcodes in a C++ project, and you have the option of using a professional library, consider trying the free evaluation of [LEADTOOLS Barcode SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode). (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). I tried the image you posted and it was readily recognized using the SDK. The library supports Windows, Linux, macOS, Android, and iOS (but you might need to use other languages like C# for some of these operating systems.)